# Choice of language/paradigm for a rule matching system

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages

I maintain an internal Java application that is nothing more than a set of rules, implemented by what amounts to a massive cascade of if/else statements.

```
if(string1.equals(earlierString)){
  if(!!string2.equals("YADAYADA")){
     errorReport.add("BLAHBLAHYADAYDA error.");
  }
  else{
    if(string3.equals("MAYBENOT!")){
      errorReport.add("POSSIBLE error");
    }
  }
}
```

and so on and so forth...

Going forward, I have significant freedom to choose how to rewrite it, even if it requires learning time and training, so no options are really off the table.  What languages and high-level design paradigms would fit this problem the best?  My main goal is to make something that is easier to update with minor/moderate rule changes.

Comment: There are a huge number of existing engines. Google it. In particular, this will overlap with workflow management engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context you are providing is pretty obscure, nevertheless I would recommend to have a look at [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/), at least to see if the [rule programming paradigm](http://www.slideshare.net/hemapani/rules-programming-tutorial) suits your needs.

The advantage with rule based languages is that they offer for free an engine to evaluate rules and fire them according to some criterion (is this maybe too much for your rule set?) allowing you to specify rules in a declarative fashion (they are 'apart' from the engine which you do not need to define).

Each rule can be viewed as a two part template:

```
part_to_match => actions_to_do
```

CLIPS engine works by *forward chaining* rules, [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) by *backward* chaining them.